# Ajax - послать запрос от определенного URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Возникла необходимость посылать запрос в ajax'e через чужой сайт, так как запросы принимаются только с него. Использую расширение, чтобы иметь возможность слать запрос, но так как я не только шлю запрос на другой сайт, но и с другого отсылаю, поэтому приходится делать `windows.open()` с каким-то GET запросом (например `?accept`) и отлавливать его и с этого окна уже слать AJAX.

Вопрос: можно ли как-то не мудрить с `windows.open()`? Это выходит не очень хорошо, так как при открытии страницы, тратится время на ее загрузку и в добавок всплывающее окно закрывает обзор пользователю на короткое время.

Вот пример кода:

```
 var geturl = window.location.href.split('?')[1];
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
    window.open('https://first-site.com?accept');
});
//так как это расширение, то работает и в window.open() который открылся выше
if(geturl == 'accept'){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://second-site.com/accept',
        data: {
            dataid: '...',
            passid: '...',
        },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(){window.close();}
    });
}
```

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45391699/

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам поможет jsonp

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: 'id=10',
  url: 'http://myotherserver.com/getdata',
  success: function () {
    // do stuff
  },
});
```

https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-jsonp

Альтернативный путь сделать что-то вроде прокси на своем сайте. Посылаете аякс запрос на свой сайт, а там уже PHP скрипт делает запрос на другой сайт и возвращает ответ.